# How to define CSS rules for React Application?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am new to inline styling in a small react project. The CSS library Bulma is helping to achive some aesthetic on my application. May I ask please How to define multiple CSS rules inside the React/JSX application? )

```
  const viewTemplate = (
      <div className="box" style={{width:"500px", margin-left:"auto", margin-top:"50px", margin-right:"auto"}}>
        <article className="c-media">
            <div className="media-content">
                
                {/*Content*/}
                <div class="content">
                    {/* To DO List Item*/}
                    
                    <label className="todo-label" htmlFor={props.id}>
                    <strong style={{ fontWeight: props.important ? 'bold' : 'normal' , fontSize: "26px"}}>{props.name}</strong>
                    </label>


                    {/* Date, Time & Important Tag*/}

                    <div>
                        <small>04.01.2021,</small><small>17:00 Uhr</small>
                        <span class="tag is-danger is-normal">IMPORTANT</span>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        This is your first To Do Task. It is very important.
                    </div>
                </div>
                     {/* Buttons */}
                    <div className="buttons">
                   
                    <button 
                        type="button" 
                        className="button is-edit"
                        onClick={()=> setEditing(true)}
                    >
                    Edit <span className="visually-hidden">{props.name}</span>
                    </button>

                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="button is-danger"
                        onClick={() => props.deleteTask(props.id)}
                    >
                    Delete <span className="visually-hidden">{props.name}</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            
            </div>
          </article>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to import your separate styles files in an index instead. Inline styling should be avoided: give IDs and class names to your components, then declare CSS (as well as Sass, etc.) in a separate file. You can always import these in `App.css` or create indexes for each component. If you’re using Bulma, I guess you’re already importing its Sass files in `App.css`. Just change the folders and do the same for your components, adding:

```
@import 'path/to/your/component/style.scss'
```

in `App.css`. Change this line accordingly to import CSS. IMHO, creating a single component folder with an index that imports all of their files works better.

Comment: thank you for your answer:

I followed your advice but following error happened:

./src/index.css
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\pythonbuddha\Desktop\Projects\to-do-list\src\index.css'

Comment: it should be `@import './index.css'` from the same directory: AFAIK, `App.css` is under `src/`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that ?

```js
<div style={{marginTop: "20px", backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
  This is your first To Do Task. It is very important.
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. 

Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Comment: @pythonbuddha For this problem you mentioned, you can use string interpolation. Like:

`style={{marginRight: \`${spacing}em\`}}`

Comment: Yes, you can use template string

Answer (score 0):

you can try in your blade html using

```
@push('styles')
<style>
</style>
@endpush
```

or

```
@push('styles')
    <link href="" rel="stylesheet" />
    @endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inline style in your jsx like:

```
<some tag style={{property1 : 'value1', property2 : 'value2'}}/>
```

or use internal style variables in your js like:

```
<some tag style={style1}/>

let style1={
   property1: 'value1',
   property2: 'value2',
   property3: 'value3',}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some variables to your React inline-styles, you should do this:

```js
<div style={{marginRight: `${spacing}em`}}></div>
```